# intermittent exception from a spark job: Schema for type scala.collection.Map[String,String] is not supported

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I keep intermittently hitting the following exception in my spark job:

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type scala.collection.Map[String,String] is not supported
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$schemaFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:780)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$schemaFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:715)
>       at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeConstraints$UndoLog.undo(TypeConstraints.scala:56)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$class.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:824)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:39)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:714)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$schemaFor$1$$anonfun$apply$8.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:776)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$schemaFor$1$$anonfun$apply$8.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:775)
>       at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
>       at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
>       at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
>       at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
>       at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:285)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$schemaFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:775)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$schemaFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:715)
>       at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeConstraints$UndoLog.undo(TypeConstraints.scala:56)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$class.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:824)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:39)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:714)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:711)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.functions$.udf(functions.scala:3382)
>   ...

I then look into the source in ScalaReflection.scala, it looks like Map[String, String] should be always a valid type in schemaFor(..) function as for line at 
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/1a5e460762593c61b7ff2c5f3641d406706616ff/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/ScalaReflection.scala#L742
where it shows

```
case t if t <:< localTypeOf[Map[_, _]] =>
    val TypeRef(_, _, Seq(keyType, valueType)) = t
    val Schema(valueDataType, valueNullable) = schemaFor(valueType)
    Schema(MapType(schemaFor(keyType).dataType,
```

Does anyone know in what case Map[String, String] can miss this check and then fall into the case "other"?

also this issue is hard to reproduce, it happens randomly once per thousands of runs.

Comment: Please try to provide a [mcve].

Comment: I've started encountering this recently on some code.
It seems I could cause this to happen by writing to the same table in two separate threads in parallel.

Comment: Getting this same problem intermittently, smells like a bug to me

Comment: Appears to be related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55150590/thread-safety-in-scala-reflection-with-type-matching