# Is Spark rdd.toDF() thread-safe?

Tags: multithreading, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have an application that runs in a Spark-2.4.4 cluster and it transforms two RDD to DataFrame with `rdd.toDF()` then outputs them to file.

For slave resource usage optimization, the application executes the job in multi-thread. The code snippet looks like this:

```scala
    import spark.implicits._
    
    Seq(rdd1, rdd2).par.foreach { rdd =>
      rdd.toDF().write.text("xxx")
    }
```

And I found that `toDF()` is not thread-safe. The application failed sometimes by `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`.

You can reproduce it from the following code snippet (1% to happen, it's easier to happen when the case class has a large number of fields.):

```scala
    package example
    
    import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
    
    object SparkToDF {
    
      case class SampleData(
                             field_1: Option[Int] = None,
                             field_2: Option[Long] = Some(0L),
                             field_3: Option[Double] = None,
                             field_4: Option[Float] = None,
                             field_5: Option[Short] = None,
                             field_6: Option[Byte] = None,
                             field_7: Option[Boolean] = Some(false),
                             field_8: Option[StructData] = Some(StructData(Some(0), Some(0L), None, None, None, None, None)),
                             field_9: String = "",
                             field_10: String = "",
                             field_11: String = "",
                             field_12: String = "",
                             field_13: String = "",
                             field_14: String = "",
                             field_15: String = "",
                             field_16: String = "",
                             field_17: String = "",
                             field_18: String = "",
                             field_19: String = "",
                             field_20: String = "",
                             field_21: String = "",
                             field_22: String = "",
                             field_23: String = "",
                             field_24: String = "",
                             field_25: String = "",
                             field_26: String = "",
                             field_27: String = "",
                             field_28: String = "",
                             field_29: String = "",
                             field_30: String = "",
                             field_31: String = "",
                             field_32: String = "",
                             field_33: String = "",
                             field_34: String = "",
                             field_35: String = "",
                             field_36: String = "",
                             field_37: String = "",
                             field_38: String = "",
                             field_39: String = "",
                             field_40: String = "",
                             field_41: String = "",
                             field_42: String = "",
                             field_43: String = "",
                             field_44: String = "",
                             field_45: String = "",
                             field_46: String = "",
                             field_47: String = "",
                             field_48: String = "",
                             field_49: String = "",
                             field_50: String = "",
                             field_51: String = "",
                             field_52: String = "",
                             field_53: String = "",
                             field_54: String = "",
                             field_55: String = "",
                             field_56: String = "",
                             field_57: String = "",
                             field_58: String = "",
                             field_59: String = "",
                             field_60: String = ""
                           )
    
      case class StructData(
                             field_1: Option[Int],
                             field_2: Option[Long],
                             field_3: Option[Double],
                             field_4: Option[Float],
                             field_5: Option[Short],
                             field_6: Option[Byte],
                             field_7: Option[Boolean]
                           )
    
      def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        val spark = SparkSession.builder()
          .appName("ThreadSafeToDF()")
          .getOrCreate()
    
        import spark.implicits._
    
        try {
          (1 to 10).par.foreach { _ =>
            (1 to 10000).map(_ => SampleData()).toDF()
          }
        } finally {
          spark.close()
        }
      }
    }
```

```sh
    for i in {1..200}; do
      echo "iter: $i (`date`)"; 
      ./bin/spark-submit --class sample.SparkToDF your.jar
    done
```

You may get a similar exception message: `Schema for type A is not supported`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type scala.Option[scala.Float] is not supported                                                                                                                
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$schemaFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:812)                                                                                                                                
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$schemaFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:743)                                                                                                                                
        at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeConstraints$UndoLog.undo(TypeConstraints.scala:56)                                                                                                                                                  
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$class.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:929)                                                                                                                            
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:49)                                                                                                                                  
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:742)                                                                                                                                                
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$deserializerFor$1$$anonfun$7.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:407)                                                                
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$deserializerFor$1$$anonfun$7.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:406)                                                                
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)                                                                                                                                                   
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)                                                                                                                                                   
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)                                                                                                                                                                            
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)                                                                                                                                                              
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:296)                                                                                                                                                                                
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$deserializerFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:406)                                                                           
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$deserializerFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:176)
        at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeConstraints$UndoLog.undo(TypeConstraints.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$class.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:929)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$deserializerFor(ScalaReflection.scala:176)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.deserializerFor(ScalaReflection.scala:164)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder$.apply(ExpressionEncoder.scala:72)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders$.product(Encoders.scala:275)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.LowPrioritySQLImplicits$class.newProductEncoder(SQLImplicits.scala:248)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLImplicits.newProductEncoder(SQLImplicits.scala:34)
```

From the error message, the exception was caused by `ScalaReflection.schemaFor()`.

I had looked at the code, it seems like Spark uses Scala reflection to get the data type and as I know there is a concurrency issue in Scala reflection.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-26555

[Thread Safety in Scala reflection with type matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55150590/thread-safety-in-scala-reflection-with-type-matching)

Is this an expected behavior? I can not find any document about thread-safe in creating DataFrame.

I had workarounded this by adding a lock when transforming RDD to DataFrame.

```scala
    object toDFLock
    
    import spark.implicits
    
    Seq(rdd1, rdd2).par.foreach { rdd =>
      toDFLock.synchronized(rdd.toDF()).write.text("xxx")
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean you "found" it not to be thread safe? By your testing or by some doc?

Comment: I just post the reproduce code snippet. @Poohl